# mySQL - query to fetch first 2 records with unique values for specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an app that records and processes product orders. From the time the order is initially created to when it is finally submitted for fulfillment, 1 or more of its properties may be changed 1 or more times by 1 or more employees along the way. I'm storing the Order Numbers and the Employees who started the orders in 1 table and then all changes to all the orders (including starting details) in another table. Something like this:

**Orders**

```
ORDER_ID   EMPLOYEE
1          dan
2          dan
3          fred
```

**Order_Activity**

```
ACTIVITY_ID    ORDER_ID    UPDATER    DATE      QTY    SIZE    COLOR    STATUS
1               1          dan        1/1/2017  5      m       red      new
2               1          dan        1/3/2017  15     m       red      updated
3               1          tom        1/9/2017  15     l       red      submitted
4               2          dan        1/1/2017  25     l       blue     new
5               2          tom        1/1/2017  25     l       blue     submitted
6               3          fred       1/9/2017  15     s       red      new
7               3          fred       1/10/2017 5      l       red      updated
8               3          fred       1/11/2017 5      m        red     updated
9               3          tom        1/11/2017 5      m        red     submitted
```

I need to display the 2 most recent orders with the employee who initiated the order as well as the orders' properties (qty, size and color) as they were when the status was changed to 'submitted'.

If I only needed **ONE** order (the most recent), I think I could use:

```
SELECT 
    Orders.EMPLOYEE, 
    Order_Activity.QTY, 
    Order_Activity.SIZE,
    Order_Activity.COLOR FROM Orders 
        INNER JOIN Order_Activity 
            ON Orders.ORDER_ID = Order_Activity.ORDER_ID 
            ORDER BY Order_Activity.date DESC LIMIT 1
```

However I am having a hard time envisioning how to find the next record with a different value for `ORDER_ID` while keeping it all in one query.

Can anyone help me with a query to produce something like this (based on the data provided above):

```
ORDER_ID    EMPLOYEE    QTY    SIZE    COLOR
3           fred        5      m       red
1           dan         15     l       red
```

or can't it even be done in 1 query?

Comment: In MS SQL I should have to advise you the next query:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a inner join with the subquery for max date  group da order_id

```
select o.ORDER_ID, o.EMPLOYEE , oa.QTY, oa.SIZE, oa.SIZE
from Orders o 
inner join  Order_Activity oa on o.ORDER_ID = oa.ORDER_ID 
inner join  (
  select  ORDER_ID, max(date) max_date
  from Order_Activity
  group by ORDER_ID 
) tt on tt.ORDER_ID = o.ORDER_ID 
    and tt.max_date = oa.date
```

Comment: I had to sort by descending date and limit rows to 2, but this did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you would have MS SQL then I should have to advise you the next query:

```
WITH prepare AS
(
SELECT 
     Orders.EMPLOYEE
    , Order_Activity.QTY
    , Order_Activity.SIZE
    , Order_Activity.COLOR
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Orders.ORDER_ID ORDER BY Order_Activity."date") AS rnbr
FROM Orders 
        INNER JOIN Order_Activity 
            ON Orders.ORDER_ID = Order_Activity.ORDER_ID 
)
SELECT

prepare.EMPLOYEE
, prepare.QTY
, prepare.SIZE
, prepare.COLOR

FROM prepare
WHERE prepare.nmbr = 1
```

You may try this statement in My SQL because this query conducts to a Standart SQL.